# Grid Search with Recursive Feature Elimination in scikit-learn pipeline returns an error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to chain Grid Search and Recursive Feature Elimination in a Pipeline using scikit-learn.

GridSearchCV and RFE with "bare" classifier works fine:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn import feature_selection
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVR

X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)

est = SVR(kernel="linear")

selector = feature_selection.RFE(est)
param_grid = dict(estimator__C=[0.1, 1, 10])
clf = GridSearchCV(selector, param_grid=param_grid, cv=10)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Putting classifier in a pipeline returns an error: RuntimeError: The classifier does not expose "coef_" or "feature_importances_" attributes

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn import feature_selection
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import pipeline
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVR

X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)

est = SVR(kernel="linear")

std_scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
pipe_params = [('std_scaler', std_scaler), ('clf', est)]
pipe = pipeline.Pipeline(pipe_params)

selector = feature_selection.RFE(pipe)
param_grid = dict(estimator__clf__C=[0.1, 1, 10])
clf = GridSearchCV(selector, param_grid=param_grid, cv=10)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

**EDIT:**

I have realised that I was not clear describing the problem. This is the clearer snippet:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn import feature_selection
from sklearn import pipeline
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVR

X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)

# This will work
est = SVR(kernel="linear")
selector = feature_selection.RFE(est)
clf = GridSearchCV(selector, param_grid={'estimator__C': [1, 10]})
clf.fit(X, y)

# This will not work
est = pipeline.make_pipeline(SVR(kernel="linear"))
selector = feature_selection.RFE(est)
clf = GridSearchCV(selector, param_grid={'estimator__svr__C': [1, 10]})
clf.fit(X, y)
```

As you can see, the only difference is putting the estimator in a pipeline. Pipeline, however, hides "coef_" or "feature_importances_" attributes. The questions are:

1. Is there a nice way of dealing with this in scikit-learn?
2. If not, is this behaviour desired for any reason?

**EDIT2:**

Updated, working snippet based on the answer provided by @Chris

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn import feature_selection
from sklearn import pipeline
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVR


class MyPipe(pipeline.Pipeline):

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        """Calls last elements .coef_ method.
        Based on the sourcecode for decision_function(X).
        Link: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/pipeline.py
        ----------
        """
        super(MyPipe, self).fit(X, y, **fit_params)
        self.coef_ = self.steps[-1][-1].coef_
        return self


X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)

# Without Pipeline
est = SVR(kernel="linear")
selector = feature_selection.RFE(est)
clf = GridSearchCV(selector, param_grid={'estimator__C': [1, 10, 100]})
clf.fit(X, y)
print(clf.grid_scores_)

# With Pipeline
est = MyPipe([('svr', SVR(kernel="linear"))])
selector = feature_selection.RFE(est)
clf = GridSearchCV(selector, param_grid={'estimator__svr__C': [1, 10, 100]})
clf.fit(X, y)
print(clf.grid_scores_)
```

Comment: I would introspect the source code to check what chain of events leads to the RuntimeError. It is quite possible that you might be able to override the properties of the relevant return object and simply add back in the variables - for example, if they are the same when returned from the SVR(). In any case, make_pipeline() might not return the same type of object as SVR() does.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have an issue with your use of pipeline.

A pipeline works as below:

first object is applied to data when you call .fit(x,y) etc. If that method exposes a .transform() method, this is applied and this output is used as the input for the next stage.

A pipeline can have any valid model as a final object, but all previous ones MUST expose a .transform() method.

Just like a pipe - you feed in data and each object in the pipeline takes the previous output and does another transform on it.

As we can see,

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html#sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.fit_transform

RFE exposes a transform method, and so should be included in the pipeline itself.
E.g.

```
some_sklearn_model=RandomForestClassifier()
selector = feature_selection.RFE(some_sklearn_model)
pipe_params = [('std_scaler', std_scaler), ('RFE', rfe),('clf', est)]
```

Your attempt has a few issues. 
Firstly, you are trying to scale a slice of your data. Imagine I had two partitions [1,1], [10,10]. If I normalize by the mean of the partition I lose the information that my second partition is significantly above the mean. You should scale at the start, not in the middle.

Secondly, SVR does not implement a transform method, you cannot incorporate it as a non final element in a pipeline.

RFE takes in a model which it fits to the data and then evaluates the weight of each feature.

**EDIT:**

You can include this behaviour if you wish, by wrapping the sklearn pipeline in your own class. What we want to do is when we fit the data, retrieve the last estimators .coef_ method and store that locally in our derived class under the correct name. 
I suggest you look into the sourcecode on github as this is only a first start and more error checking etc would probably be required. Sklearn uses a function decorator called `@if_delegate_has_method` which would be a handy thing to add to ensure the method generalises. I have run this code to make sure it works runs, but nothing more.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn import feature_selection
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import pipeline
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVR

class myPipe(pipeline.Pipeline):

    def fit(self, X,y):
        """Calls last elements .coef_ method.
        Based on the sourcecode for decision_function(X).
        Link: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/pipeline.py
        ----------
        """

        super(myPipe, self).fit(X,y)

        self.coef_=self.steps[-1][-1].coef_
        return

X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)

est = SVR(kernel="linear")

selector = feature_selection.RFE(est)
std_scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
pipe_params = [('std_scaler', std_scaler),('select', selector), ('clf', est)]

pipe = myPipe(pipe_params)



selector = feature_selection.RFE(pipe)
clf = GridSearchCV(selector, param_grid={'estimator__clf__C': [2, 10]})
clf.fit(X, y)

print clf.best_params_
```

if anything is not clear, please ask.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for your answer. I was not clear describing the problem. I specifically wonder how to access "coef_" or "feature_importances_" attributes of an estimator which seem to be hidden by the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I think you had a slightly different way of constructing the pipeline than what was listed in the [pipeline documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html).

Are you looking for this?

```
X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)

est = SVR(kernel="linear")

std_scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
selector = feature_selection.RFE(est)
pipe_params = [('feat_selection',selector),('std_scaler', std_scaler), ('clf', est)]
pipe = pipeline.Pipeline(pipe_params)

param_grid = dict(clf__C=[0.1, 1, 10])
clf = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=param_grid, cv=2)
clf.fit(X, y)
print clf.grid_scores_
```

Also see this [useful example](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/auto_examples/feature_stacker.html) for combining things in a pipeline. For the `RFE` object, I just used the [official documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html) for constructing it with your SVR estimator - I then just put the `RFE` object into the pipeline in the same way as you had done with the scaler and estimator objects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but your solution works different then I intended. 

Your workflow: 
1. During the GridSearchCV features are selected using `RFE(SVR())` with default value of `C`. 
2. Then, those selected features are scaled.
3. `SVR()` is fitted with one parameter from `param_grid`.

My desired workflow is the following:
1. During the GridSearchCV features are scaled.
2. `SVR()` is fitted with one parameter from `param_grid`.
3. Then, the features with the smallest weights are pruned from the model.
4. Steps 1-3 are repeated until the desired number of features to select is reached.