# RFE ranking with Gridsearch

Tags: python, pipeline, rfe

I want to use RFE for feature selection in a pipeline. I have no problems getting it to work in pipelines without GridSearch. However, when I try to incorporate GridSearch, I keep getting a value error (NB. the models are fine without RFE).

I have tried to use feature_selection as was suggested in this topic: [Grid Search with Recursive Feature Elimination in scikit-learn pipeline returns an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683230/grid-search-with-recursive-feature-elimination-in-scikit-learn-pipeline-returns), but this results in the same error.

What could be wrong?

**my error:**
*ValueError: Invalid parameter alpha for estimator RFE(estimator=Ridge(alpha=1.0, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=None,
normalize=True, random_state=None, solver='auto',
tol=0.001),
n_features_to_select=4, step=1, verbose=1). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.*

**this works fine:**

```
rfe=RFE(estimator=LinearRegression(), n_features_to_select=4, verbose=1)

#setup the pipeline steps
steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler()),
         ('imputation', SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.NaN, strategy='most_frequent')), 
         ('reg',  rfe)]
          
# Create the pipeline: pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

# Create train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)


# Fit the pipeline to the training set: 
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict the labels of the test set
y_pred = pipeline.predict(X_test)

print()
# Print the features and their ranking (high = dropped early on)
print(dict(zip(X.columns, rfe.ranking_)))
# Print the features that are not eliminated
print(X.columns[rfe.support_])
print()

print("R^2: {}".format(pipeline.score(X_test, y_test)))
rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
print("Root Mean Squared Error: {}".format(rmse))
```

**this doesn't work**

```
rfe=RFE(estimator=Ridge(normalize=True), n_features_to_select=4, verbose=1)

#setup the pipeline steps
steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler()),
         ('imputation', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.NaN, strategy='most_frequent')), 
         ('ridge', rfe)]
          
# Create the pipeline: pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

#Define hyperparameters and range of Grid Search
parameters = {"ridge__alpha": np.linspace(0,1,100)}

# Create train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

# run cross validation
cv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid = parameters, cv=3)

# Fit the pipeline to the training set: 
cv.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict the labels of the test set
y_pred = cv.predict(X_test)

# Compute and print R^2 and RMSE
print("R^2: {}".format(cv.score(X_test, y_test)))
rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
print("Root Mean Squared Error: {}".format(rmse))
print("Tuned Model Parameters: {}".format(cv.best_params_))
```

**using feature_selection also doesn't work**

```
selector = feature_selection.RFE(Ridge(normalize=True))

#setup the pipeline steps
steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler()),
         ('imputation', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.NaN, strategy='most_frequent')), 
         ('RFE', selector)]
          
# Create the pipeline: pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is old, but in case someone stumbles upon it:

You can access the hyperparameter alpha or any parameter of the estimator inside feature_selection(estimator=) with the parameter '<feature_selection>__estimator__<your parameter>':

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE

model = RFE(estimator=Ridge())

pipe = Pipeline(
    steps = [
        ("scaler", StandardScaler()),
        ("rfe", model)
    ]
)

param = {
    "rfe__step" : np.linspace(0.1, 1, 10),
    "rfe__estimator__alpha" : np.logspace(-3, 3, 7)
}

tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5).split(X_train)

gridsearch = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, cv=tscv, param_grid=param, refit=True, return_train_score=True, n_jobs=-1)
fit = gridsearch.fit(X_train, y_train)
```